# How can I return a String of an object in a class in c++?

Tags: c++, string, class

I want to have access of a string which is part of my class and I can't seem to make it work.
Here's the example code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<vector>


class element {
    std::string Name;
    int Z;
    double N;
  public:
    element (std::string,int,double);
    double M (void) {return (Z+N);}
    std::string NameF () {return (Name);}
};

element::element (std::string Name, int Z, double N) {

    Name=Name;
    Z=Z;
    N=N;
}

int main () {


  element H ("Hydrogen",1,1.);
  element O ("Oxygen",8,8);

    std::vector<element> H2O ={H,H,O};

    std::cout<<"Mass of " <<O.NameF()<<" is: " << O.M() << std::endl;
    std::cout<<H2O[1].NameF()<<std::endl;

  return 0;
  }
```

I am not able to get a string out of my objects in the class...
Maybe I can't even get them into the class.
Does the standard constructor work like that with strings?
I just want a sting (i.e. a name) of my objects that I can call.
What's the proper way to do so?

I'd appreciate any help,

cheers
Niko

Comment: `Name=Name;` assigns the function parameter to itself, and does nothing to the member.

Comment: Naming collision between the member variable and the parameter. The [Member Initiallizer List](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list) can help you here

Comment: or `this->Name=Name`, but really just change the parameter or member name.

Answer (score 4):

For *constructors* you should use an *initialization list* where the compiler knows the difference between the parameter and the member:

```
class element {
    std::string Name;
    int Z;
    double N;
  public:
    element (std::string,int,double);
    double M (void) {return (Z+N);}
    std::string NameF () {return (Name);}
};

element::element (std::string Name, int Z, double N)
: Name(Name), Z(Z), N(N) // <- the compiler knows which is parameter and which is member
{
    // no need to put anything here for this
}
```

Otherwise you can differentiate explicitly using `this`:

```
void element::set_name(std::string const& Name)
{
    // tell the compiler which is the member of `this`
    // and which is the parameter
    this->Name = Name; 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you use the name of a member as a name for a parameter, you need to access the member via the `this` pointer.

So change:

```
Name=Name;
```

to

```
this->Name = Name;
```

And the same goes for the other two:

```
this->Z = Z;
this->N = N;
```